# How to read the nested elements from the xml in pyspark?

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to read the nested elements from the xml in pyspark?

[image]

Comment: you meant like `col('Address._Address1')` or `col('Address.State')`? Plus please post the schema or input or output or code by text not images

Comment: I don't have access to pyspark anymore, but maybe this will work for you. 

https://medium.com/@tennysusanto/use-databricks-spark-xml-to-parse-nested-xml-d7d7cf797c28

Comment: Or, this.

https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-write-xml/

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to flatten a nested XML and convert to a Dataframe in Pyspark

**Step 1:** Convert the XML to a raw dataframe using the below script

```
%%pyspark
df = spark.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
    .option("rootTag", "your root tag") \
    .option("rowTag", "your row tag") \
    .option("valueTag", True) \
    .load('file.xml')

display(df)
```

**Step 2:** Convert the nested tab to a JSON using `to_json` function before we read the nested tab.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json
df_new = df.withColumn("Address",to_json("Address"))
display(df_new)
```

**Step3:** Use `from_json` function with the corresponding schema to parse the json string.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

json_schema = "_Address1 string, \
               _Address2 string, \
               _City string, \
               State string"
df = df_new.withColumn("x", F.from_json("Address", json_schema)).select("*", "x.*")
display(df)
```

Flattened DataFrame will be displayed. You can remove the unwanted column based on your need using the below script.

```
d = df.select("Name","_Address1","_Address2","_City","State","Country")
display(d)
```